# htaccess RewriteRule cause loop

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

please, could you give me an advice, why this .htaccess file cause redirect loop?

I have this url:
**www.akomin.cz/** or **www.akomin.cz/smth/**
and I want to redirect it there: 
**www.akomin.cz/nedostupny/**

But Safari throws me an error, that while trying to open **www.akomin.cz/nedostupny/** there were many redirects.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule !^/nedostupny/ /nedostupny/ [L,R=302]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Nothing to do with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your first rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/nedostupny/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /nedostupny/ [L,R=302]
```

You need to use `%{THE_REQUEST}` because your last rule is changing `REQUEST_URI` to `/index.php` hence causing first rule to fire again. `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.